# Find the first Recurring letter in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, for-loop, recurring

I wrote the code as follows but it doesn't return the first recurring letter properly.

*Example:*

In the word `"statistics"` the recurring letters are `s`, `t`, and `i`. But the letter `t` recurs sooner than the letter `s` and `i`, but my program returns `s` instead of `t`.

What do I need to do for it to return `t`, using **two for loops**, as per the task in hand?

```java
public class Main {
    public static char FRL(String word){
        for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j<word.length(); j++){
                if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j)){
                    return word.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return '0';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "statistics";
        if (FRL(word) != '0'){
            System.out.println(FRL(word));
        }else{
            System.out.println("No reccurring letter!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, *two for loops* are an requirement? Just making sure cause that is an rather slow implementation and there are simple faster implementations.

Comment: The 's' appears first in the test word, then the inner loop scans the remainder of the test word for another 's'. You need to redefine what "recurring sooner" means.

Comment: @Mushroomator yes, It is a requirement of my "ADS" class, to implement 3 "algorithms",
1. using 2 for loops or naive method (O(n^2))
2. using an early exit from the loop
3. using dictionaries or sets

Comment: @nicomp By recurring sooner I mean which one recurs first:
**s**tati**s**tics - 4 steps
s**t**a**t**istics - 1 steps

Comment: Then your algorithm is incorrect. You need to take a step back and redesign the algo. The code isn't wrong, it just doesn't do what you think it should be doing. Design, then code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce eliminate the nested loop and improve the performance by storing every encountered character in a `HashSet`:

```
public static char FRL(String word){
    Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char next = word.charAt(i);
        if (!seen.add(next)) {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return '0';
}
```

But if you have a requirement to use a nested loop, then you should fix the *initialization expression* and *condition* of the inner `for` loop, i.e. we should be check characters starting from index `0` inclusive and up to index `i` exclusive:

```
public static char FRL(String word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char next = word.charAt(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(next == word.charAt(j)) {
                return next;
            }
        }
    }
    return '0';
}
```

By the way, `getFirstRecuringLetter()` would be a better method name than `FRL`.

Comment: I'd recommend adding `char c = word.charAt(i)` as the first line of the outer loop body, and then refer to that instead of calling `charAt(i)` repeatedly within the inner loop. Not a huge efficiency difference in this specific case (unless some "words" are very long) but a good habit to get into.

Comment: @Bobulous Agree, it's better to introduce a variable. Amended.